# I'm having errors with a voting code for class

Tags: c#

This code is suppose to allow the person to vote for a candidate, return to the main menu and review the results before closing the program.
Here's the current code:

```
using System;
class Voting {

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while(true)
    {
     MainMenu();
    }
}

 private bool MainMenu()
 {
      string  selection;
      int person    = 0;
      int rperson   = 0;
      int choice    = 0;
      int Bennet    = 0;
      int Biden     = 0;
      int Warren    = 0;
      int Bloomberg = 0;
      int Steyer    = 0;
      int Buttigieg = 0;
      int Gabbard   = 0;
      int Kolbuchar = 0;
      int Patrick   = 0;
      int Sanders   = 0;
      int Yang      = 0;
      int Trump     = 0;
      int Weld      = 0;
      int Walsh     = 0;
// *************** M A I N  M E N U ******************//.
// Console.Clear();
      while (choice > 0 && choice < 4)
          {
            Console.WriteLine("Iowa Caucus Voting");
            Console.WriteLine("Choose an option:");
            Console.WriteLine("1) Democrat");
            Console.WriteLine("2) Republican");
            Console.WriteLine("3) See Results");
            Console.WriteLine("4) Exit");
            Console.Write("\r\n Select an option: ");
            selection = Console.ReadLine();
            choice    = Convert.ToInt32(selection);


            while (choice < 1 || choice > 4 )
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Valid choices are 1 through 4");
                Console.WriteLine("Please select an option");
                Console.WriteLine("\r\n select 1 through 4: ");
                selection = Console.ReadLine();
                choice = Convert.ToInt32(selection);
                break;
            }
        }

      switch (choice)
         {
            case 1:
                {
             Console.Clear();
             Console.WriteLine("Please vote for the following:");
             Console.WriteLine("1)  Michael Bennet");
             Console.WriteLine("2)  Joe Biden");
             Console.WriteLine("3)  Mike Bloomberg");
             Console.WriteLine("4)  Pete Buttigieg");
             Console.WriteLine("5)  Tulsi Gabbard");
             Console.WriteLine("6)  Amy Kolbuchar");
             Console.WriteLine("7)  Deval Patrick");
             Console.WriteLine("8)  Tom Steyer");
             Console.WriteLine("9)  Bernie Sanders");
             Console.WriteLine("10) Elizabeth Warren");
             Console.WriteLine("11) Andrew Yang");
             Console.WriteLine("\r\n Select an option");
             selection= Console.ReadLine();
             person = Convert.ToInt32(selection);
             break;

             switch (person)
                {
                    case 1:
                    {
                    Console.WriteLine("You have voted for Micheal Bennet");
                    Bennet++;
                    return true;
                    }

                    case 2:
                    {
                    Console.WriteLine("You have voted for Joe Biden");
                    Biden++;
                    return true;
                    }
                    case 3:
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You have voted for Mike Bloomberg");
                        Bloomberg++;
                        return true;
                    }
                    case 4 :
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You have voted for Pete Buttigieg");
                        Buttigieg++;
                        return true;
                    }
                    case 5:
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You have voted for Tulsi Gabbard");
                        Gabbard++;
                        return true;
                    }
                    case 6:
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You have voted for Amy Kolbuchar");
                        Kolbuchar++;
                        return true;
                    }
                    case 7:
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You have voted for Deval Patrick");
                        Patrick++;
                        return true;
                    }
                    case 8:
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You have voted for Tom Steyer");
                        Steyer++;
                        return true;
                    }
                    case 9:
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You have voted for Bernie Sanders");
                        Sanders++;
                        return true;
                    }
                    case 10:
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You have voted for Elizabeth Warren");
                        Warren++;
                        return true;
                    }
                    case 11:
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You have voted for Andrew Yang");
                        Yang++;
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
                case 2:
                {
             Console.Clear();
             Console.WriteLine("Please vote for the following:");
             Console.WriteLine("1)  Michael Bennet");
             Console.WriteLine("2)  Joe Biden");
             Console.WriteLine("3)  Mike Bloomberg");
             Console.WriteLine("\r\n Select an option");
             selection= Console.ReadLine();
             rperson = Convert.ToInt32(selection);
             break;

             switch (rperson)
                {
                    case 1:
                    {
                    Console.WriteLine("You have voted for Donald Trump");
                    Trump++;
                    return true;
                    }

                    case 2:
                    {
                    Console.WriteLine("You have voted for Bill Weld");
                    Weld++;
                    return true;
                    }
                    case 3:
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You have voted for Josh Walsh");
                        Walsh++;
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                }
            case 3:
            {
            Console.WriteLine("Results:");
            Console.WriteLine("Democrats:");
            Console.WriteLine("Michael Bennet: ", + Bennet);
            Console.WriteLine("Joe Biden: ", + Biden);
            Console.WriteLine("Mike Bloomberg: ", + Bloomberg);
            Console.WriteLine("Pete Buttigieg: ", + Buttigieg);
            Console.WriteLine("Tulsi Gabbard: ", + Gabbard);
            Console.WriteLine("Amy Kolbuchar: ", + Kolbuchar);
            Console.WriteLine("Deval Patrick: ", + Patrick);
            Console.WriteLine("Tom Steyer: ", + Steyer);
            Console.WriteLine("Bernie Sanders: ", + Sanders);
            Console.WriteLine("Elizabeth Warren: ", + Warren);
            Console.WriteLine("Andrew Yang: ", + Yang);
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Republican:");
            Console.WriteLine("Donald Trump: ", + Trump);
            Console.WriteLine("Bill Weld: ", + Weld);
            Console.WriteLine("Josh Walsh: ", + Walsh);
            break;
            }

            case 4:
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exiting....");
                return false;
            }

         }
}
}
```

I'm not sure what exactly I did wrong but here are the errors:

```
main.cs(16,6): error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `Voting.MainMenu()'

main.cs(20,15): error CS0161: `Voting.MainMenu()': not all code paths return a value

main.cs(68,13): error CS0163: Control cannot fall through from one case label `case 1:' to another

main.cs(159,17): warning CS0162: Unreachable code detected

main.cs(171,14): warning CS0162: Unreachable code detected
```

Comment: The error messages tell you directly what you did wrong and give line numbers. `MainMenu()` is not a static member. It can only be called from an instance of the class. You are trying to call it from a `static` member, `Main`, at line 16. I don't know your context, but maybe you want `Main` to be `static` as well. The next message says that not all code paths return a value. `MainMenu` Is declared to return a `bool`. In some cases, you don't return anything. Read your other messages carefully.

Comment: There's definitely an Iowa caucus joke in here somewhere

Comment: Good try. Keep up the good work. I think you can deduct the error by moving those repetitive codes like console writeline to smaller classes, nested switch case can be moved to smaller classes too. then you will see the parts that is not returning boolean. it's too simple to give you answer. may be you should try to solve it first

Comment: I'm not the best at this, I've been at it for a while

Answer (score 1):

A member function cannot be called without object reference.

So either make the MainMenu() static. or create an object in your main method

Ex:

Solution 1:

```
private static bool MainMenu()
{
// Your code
}
```

Solution 2:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
var obj = new Voting();
    while(true)
    {
     obj.MainMenu();
    }
}
```

Looking into other bunch of errors, it seems you have some more problems.
Look at the switch case:

Having a switch construct inside another one after the case scope has been closed in the reason for Unreachable Code issue.

You need to take Programming basics 101. If a method has a return type you must return something somewhere from it. Either change that bool to void. or Add relevant return statements.

We cant help you with every line of code here. For that you must contact psuedocoder and BACON SO users. They would happily come to your home and do the homework for you.

Comment: I still have these errors

main.cs(20,22): error CS0161: `Voting.MainMenu()': not all code paths return a value

main.cs(68,13): error CS0163: Control cannot fall through from one case label `case 1:' to another

main.cs(159,17): warning CS0162: Unreachable code detected

main.cs(171,14): warning CS0162: Unreachable code detected

Comment: @MatthewCioffi "unreachable code detected" means, at that line, the compiler has detected code that cannot be reached (will not be executed since the logic of your program bypasses it). "Not all code paths return a value" means that there are ways your function can return without returning a value. Your declarations says it should return a `bool`. That means it should *always* return a `bool`, not just sometimes.